# Click a button when there are more than one button vba

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I need help with in this question: 
- click a button "previous day"

The code I have currently will login into a website, click through the transactions link, click the submit button. I'm stuck on where I need to click a button labeled "previous day". I included the html in question, I tried to used HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("gso_nominate_maint")(1).Click to try and click previous button but I get an error message.

```
Dim HMTLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub transactions()
'
' transactions Macro
'

 Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
    Dim MYURL As String
    ' Delmarva website
    MYURL = "website"
    Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
    MyBrowser.Silent = True
    MyBrowser.navigate MYURL
    MyBrowser.Visible = True
    Do
    Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
    ' user login and password
    HTMLDoc.all.user_login.value = "user"
    HTMLDoc.all.user_password.value = "pass"
    ' click submit
    HTMLDoc.forms(0).submit
    While MyBrowser.Busy Or MyBrowser.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    ' click transactions
    HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("menuitem")(0).Click
    While MyBrowser.Busy Or MyBrowser.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    'click Billing Analysis Report (Industrial)
    HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("firstlink")(1).Click
    While MyBrowser.Busy Or MyBrowser.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    HTMLDoc.forms(0).submit
    HTMLDoc.forms(0).submit
    'currently get an error from the code line below. 
    HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("gso_nominate_maint")(1).Click
    While MyBrowser.Busy Or MyBrowser.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    End Sub
```

```html
<a href="gso_etrader_main?vsCurrUser=2753" class="menuitem">Trader Home</a><span class="body"> | </span>
<a href="gso_list_etrader_transaction?vsCurrUser=2753" class="menuitem">Transaction</a><span class="body"> | </span>
<a href="gso_list_etrader_reports?vsCurrUser=2753" class="menuitem">Reports</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</td>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>
<CENTER>
<TABLE WIDTH=750 BORDER=0 ALIGN=CENTER>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=BOTTOM>
<FORM ACTION="gso_nominate_maint" METHOD="POST">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="vsCurrUser" VALUE="2753">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="vsTransactionName" VALUE="INTER_NOMINATE_ENTRY">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="vsDlyOrderKy" VALUE="13052">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Previous Day">
</FORM>
</TD>
<TD ALIGN=CENTER>
<BR>
<B><FONT SIZE="+2">N</FONT><FONT SIZE="+1">OMINATE</FONT></B>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<B><FONT SIZE="+2">O</FONT><FONT SIZE="+1">RDERS</FONT></B>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<B><FONT SIZE="+2">F</FONT><FONT SIZE="+1">OR</FONT></B>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<B><FONT SIZE="+2">Thursday  08/30/2018</FONT></B>
<BR>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-1">
<B>[ Maintenance ]</B>
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=BOTTOM>
<FORM ACTION="gso_nominate_maint" METHOD="POST">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="vsCurrUser" VALUE="2753">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="vsTransactionName" VALUE="INTER_NOMINATE_ENTRY">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="vsDlyOrderKy" VALUE="13054">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Next Day">
</FORM>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<BR>
<BR>
<TABLE WIDTH=750 BORDER=0>
<TR>
<TD WIDTH=450 ALIGN=RIGHT>&nbsp;
</TD>
<TD ALIGN=RIGHT WIDTH=50>
<FORM ACTION="gso_nominate_ff_header" METHOD="POST">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="vsOrderHdrKy" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="vsDlyOrderKy" VALUE="13053">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="vsTransactionName" VALUE="INTER_NOMINATE_ENTRY">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="vsCurrUser" VALUE="2753">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Add New">
</FORM>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE WIDTH=750 BORDER=0>
<TR>
<TH WIDTH=250 NOWRAP VALIGN=BOTTOM ALIGN=CENTER>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
SERVICE
</FONT>
</TH>
<TH WIDTH=50 NOWRAP VALIGN=BOTTOM VALIGN=CENTER>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
RANK
</FONT>
</TH>
<TH WIDTH=75 NOWRAP VALIGN=BOTTOM VALIGN=CENTER>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
NOMINATED<BR>VOLUME
</FONT>
</TH>
<TH WIDTH=75 NOWRAP VALIGN=BOTTOM VALIGN=CENTER>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
CONFIRMED<BR>VOLUME
</FONT>
</TH>
<TH WIDTH=150 NOWRAP VALIGN=BOTTOM VALIGN=CENTER>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
COMMENTS
</FONT>
</TH>
<TH WIDTH=75 NOWRAP VALIGN=BOTTOM VALIGN=CENTER>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
NOMINATED<BR>TOTAL
</FONT>
</TH>
<TH WIDTH=75 NOWRAP VALIGN=BOTTOM VALIGN=CENTER>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
CONFIRMED<BR>TOTAL
</FONT>
</TH>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD NOWRAP WIDTH=250 ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
<B><A HREF="gso_nominate_ff_header?vsOrderHdrKy=239887&vsDlyOrderKy=13053&vsTransactionName=INTER_NOMINATE_ENTRY&vsCurrUser=2753">Direct Sale Columbia</A></B>
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD NOWRAP WIDTH=50 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
&nbsp;
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD NOWRAP WIDTH=75 ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
           0
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD NOWRAP WIDTH=75 ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
           0
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD NOWRAP WIDTH=150 ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
&nbsp;
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD NOWRAP WIDTH=75 ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
           0
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD NOWRAP WIDTH=75 ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
           0
</FONT>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD NOWRAP WIDTH=250 ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
<B><A HREF="gso_nominate_ff_header?vsOrderHdrKy=239917&vsDlyOrderKy=13053&vsTransactionName=INTER_NOMINATE_ENTRY&vsCurrUser=2753">Direct Sale ESNG</A></B>
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD NOWRAP WIDTH=50 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
&nbsp;
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD NOWRAP WIDTH=75 ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
           0
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD NOWRAP WIDTH=75 ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
           0
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD NOWRAP WIDTH=150 ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
&nbsp;
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD NOWRAP WIDTH=75 ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
           0
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD NOWRAP WIDTH=75 ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
           0
</FONT>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD NOWRAP WIDTH=250 ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
<B><A HREF="gso_nominate_ff_header?vsOrderHdrKy=239947&vsDlyOrderKy=13053&vsTransactionName=INTER_NOMINATE_ENTRY&vsCurrUser=2753">Direct Sale Transco</A></B>
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD NOWRAP WIDTH=50 ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
&nbsp;
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD NOWRAP WIDTH=75 ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
           0
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD NOWRAP WIDTH=75 ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
           0
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD NOWRAP WIDTH=150 ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
&nbsp;
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD NOWRAP WIDTH=75 ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
           0
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD NOWRAP WIDTH=75 ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT FACE="ARIAL, HELVETICA" SIZE="-2">
```

Comment: You have asked 4 questions in one go in the above. That is not how SO works. I also cannot see your attempts to complete any  of these tasks in the above. And posting lots of separate bits of HTML gives us no idea how it all fits together and will likely make for long debugging sessions as we work out how it all fits together, what is potentially on refresh/new pages..... what may be missing important parent tags etc. Please limit to one problem at a time, show the relevant HTML along with your coding attempt to solve it.

Comment: For starters, you can use almost exactly the same syntax from my prior answer to attempt the first part  of this. You will need a click though rather than .Selected.

Comment: Separating these out will help clarify order as well. You describe " click details then click a button labeled diamond state generation but only #1040392" - details and 1040392 are in the same HTML extract. Clicking either may alter the page so is the order correct and are these actions valid? And there is a button labelled "1040392", not  "diamond state generation" as far as I can see so please be very accurate in your descriptions  Perhaps that button is not included? I apologise if I have misunderstood this somehow.

Comment: Should I delete this question and rephrase it again? The code     (HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("gso_nominate_maint")(1).Click) is the code I used to try to click the previous button. I was stuck at this point and just trying to give an overview of what I was trying to accomplish instead of asking one piece at a time, but if it's to confusing I can reask the question

Comment: So the thing about your third comment is, that there are actually 10 links on that html page. 5 are contracts with #10xxxx/90xxxx values and then the other 5 of the links are customers listed as "diamond state generation" under each one. So if I click the link for the contract #10xxxx it takes me to the wrong destination. I am trying to click a specific diamond state generation customer and it's the one linked to contract 1040392. Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: Personally, I would copy what you have here somewhere else. Then [edit] this question to reflect the first task and include your coding attempt at it. My prior answer to your question should pretty much be what you need I think to make a good go at that. We can deal with the 3rd comment bit later. The question overall has improved alot from your first by the way, just too many questions within a question in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the help you have provided and guidance on better question asking quality. What do you mean "copy what I have somewhere else"? I can definitely ask another question with only addressing one issue per question. I am missing what you are saying about your previous answer answering my current question. The previous question was asking about a drop down menu vs this is clicking a button aren't these actions different code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179212/discussion-between-qharr-and-mike-p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a form element to navigate before getting to that button, purely based on the HTML supplied. You then can use an CSS attribute selector to target the element by its attribute `value` and value `'Previous Day'`

```
MyBrowser.document.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).querySelector("[value='Previous Day']").Click
```

This assumes that there aren't additional form/frame/iframe tags to navigate.

You can see the parent form here:

[image]

Remember, there must be an

```
While MyBrowser.Busy Or MyBrowser.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

to allow page loading before.

You may need additional wait time such as a timed loop for the element to become available e.g.

```
Dim t As Date, ele As Object
Const WAIT_TIME_SECS As Long = 5
t = Timer

Do
    DoEvents
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ele = MyBrowser.document.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).querySelector("[value='Previous Day']")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Timer - t > WAIT_TIME_SECS Then Exit Do
Loop While ele Is Nothing

If Not ele Is Nothing Then ele.Click
```